Updating vector data in CosmosDB through Semantic Kernel
I'm using CosmosDB as a memory store for creating a chat bot in top of a bunch of markdown files. The code is configured like this:
ISemanticTextMemory semanticTextMemory = new MemoryBuilder()
    .WithTextEmbeddingGeneration(kernel.GetRequiredService<ITextEmbeddingGenerationService>())
    .WithMemoryStore(new AzureCosmosDBNoSQLMemoryStore("...", "...", 1536, VectorDataType.Float32, VectorIndexType.DiskANN))
    .Build();

I then iterate through all of the markdown files and call the SaveInformationAsync method like this:
// id is the path of the markdown file
var result = await memory.SaveInformationAsync("collection", id: id, text: content, description: description);

This is all working fine. I have an issue when updating one of the markdown files, though. I want to update the vectors which I also wrote some code for. It is just a part of the code above and generating the id in the same way. I've added some logging to make sure that the id of the two runs equal.
It seems like Semantic Kernel is inserting a new item rather than updating the existing one. When inspecting the collection through the Data Explorer, I see that the IDs are GUIDs and not the path that I provided. And when querying the data, I see two items with different ids, covering the same markdown file.
Does anyone know how this is done correctly? All of the examples I found online re-creates all vectors every time. I want to only update CosmosDB when there are updates and only with the changed parts.

By default, Semantic Kernel generates a unique identifier (GUID) for each piece of data unless you explicitly query or manage items by ID. The IDs stored in CosmosDB are unique to ensure no collisions in distributed systems. If no explicit handling is done, the kernel-generated GUIDs will always create new entries.

That explains my observation then. New items are generated on every run. Do you know if it is possible to overwrite or delete the item when needing to update? I tried using the SearchAsync method where I can get the items that I want to update/delete. But I don't see any ID on them which is needed to call RemoveAsync.
